# How can I modify the attributes of an SVG file from Python?

Tags: python, svg, lxml

I have an svg file that was generated by the map data-visualisation software 'Kartograph'. It contains a large number of paths representing areas on a map. These paths each have some data fields:

```
<path d=" ...path info... " data-electorate="Canberra" data-id="Canberra" data-no="23" data-nop="0.92" data-percentile="6" data-state="ACT" data-totalvotes="25" data-yes="2" data-yesp="0.08" id="Canberra"/>
```

So that I don't have to generate a new svg file every time, I want to modify some attributes, such as the number of 'yes' votes, from within python. Specifically, I would like to increment/increase the 'yes' votes value by one (for each execution of the code).

I have tried lxml and have browsed the documentation for it extensively, but so far this code has not worked:

```
from lxml import etree

filename = "aus4.svg"
tree = etree.parse(open(filename, 'r'))

for element in tree.iter():
    if element.tag.split("}")[1] == "path":
        if element.get("id") == "Lingiari":
            yes_votes = element.get("data-yes")
            print(yes_votes)
            yes_votes.set(yes_votes, str(int(yes_votes) + 1))
            print(yes_votes)
```

Is python the best tool to use for this task? If so how might I change the above code or start afresh. Apologies for any confusion. I am new to this 'lxml' module and svg files, so I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not set the attribute again, but use its value instead of the elmenet in this line:

```
yes_votes.set(yes_votes, str(int(yes_votes) + 1))
```

`yes_votes` contains the content of the attribute and not a reference to the attribute itself. Change it to:

```
element.set( "data-yes", str(int(yes_votes) + 1))
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Sorry for the silly question - I'd been struggling for a while and obviously had a bit of a brain-fart in overlooking that.